# Disable zoom on mobile website for Android phones

Tags: android, mobile, zooming

I am building an responsive mobile website and need to disable zooming across all devices. I have used a meta tag which should in theory prevent zooming, and which works on iOS, windows Phone and *some* Android devices, but on several Android phones zooming is still enabled. Here is the meta-tag I have used:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"

I've also tried user-scalable=0. I know this is a known bug with Android but other sites have managed to disable zoom on the same phones that i am testing on e.g. http://m.bbc.co.uk/ so there *must* be a fix out there for this. Does anyone knows a reliable fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding also  maximum-scale=1.0?
Not shure this is the solution, but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Set initial-scale=0.
Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

check this : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

*you should add this => maximum-scale=1

check this: [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
```