# What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?

Tags: html, attributes, tags, viewport, meta-tags

I was going through the source code of a website and found this piece of code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I want to know what this initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale are and what does those values mean? And also tell me what all values they accepts.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

They are viewport meta tags, and is most applicable on mobile browsers.

### width=device-width

This means, we are telling to the browser “my website adapts to your device width”.

### initial-scale

This defines the scale of the website, This parameter sets the initial zoom level, which means **1 CSS pixel** is equal to **1 viewport pixel**. This parameter help when you're changing orientation, or preventing default zooming. Without this parameter, responsive site won't work.

### maximum-scale

Maximum-scale defines the maximum zoom. When you access the website, top priority is `maximum-scale=1`, and it won’t allow the user to zoom.

### minimum-scale

Minimum-scale defines the minimum zoom. This works the same as above, but it defines the  minimum scale. This is useful, when `maximum-scale` is large, and you want to set `minimum-scale`.

### user-scalable

User-scalable assigned to **1.0** means the website is allowing the user to zoom in or zoom out.

But if you assign it to `user-scalable=no`, it means the website is not allowing the user to zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width= 640,initial-scale=0.7,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />` can you explain this ? do you think its valid ?

Comment: Is *viewport pixel* same as *device pixel*?

Comment: user-scalable should be `1.0` or `yes` ?

Comment: @overexchange No.

Comment: Actually on mobile safari, maximum-scale does not disable user zoom. It only disables automatic zooming like when you tap a text input.

Answer (score 21):

**user-scalable:**

**user-scalable=yes** (default) to allow the user to zoom in or out on the web page;

**user-scalable=no** to prevent the user from zooming in or out.

You can get more detailed information by reading the following articles.

- http://www.html-5.com/metatags/meta-viewport.html
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes
  [image]

## Demo Code (recommended)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=3.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>do not using <mark>user-scalable=no</mark></h1>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <h1>do not using <mark>user-scalable=no</mark></h1>

Comment: Thank you, finally someone who provided a proper explanation of what min/max scales do.

Answer (score 7):

`viewport` meta tag on mobile browser,

> The **initial-scale** property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. 
>   The **maximum-scale**, **minimum-scale**, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

Answer (score 3):

This meta tag is used by all responsive web pages, that is those that are designed to layout well across device types - phone, tablet, and desktop. The attributes do what they say. However, as MDN's [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) indicates,

> On high dpi screens, pages with `initial-scale=1` will effectively be
>   zoomed by browsers.

I've found that the following ensures that the page displays with zero zoom by default.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">`

Comment: Thanks @Ronnie. Worked for me but i changed from 0.86 to 0.98.

Answer (score 0):

It's for controlling aspect on mobile phones and tablets. You will find more info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

This post may help. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ It gives a full description on the meta tags and its different attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about Google Pagespeed (Lighthouse) error under the Accessibility tab. You can solve the error by replacing this code in the `header.php` file under the theme files.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

should be replaced with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=3.0">
```

You will see that the error will be solved after refreshing the Pagespeed page. If you are still seeking the error after replacing the code, just clear the cache from optimization plugins or the Hosting side.