# Onsen zoom/enlarge images

Tags: ios, image, onsen-ui, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Is it possible to enable zoom/pinch to enlarge images with onsen UI - or maybe open a graphic in a new view to zoom-in somehow?

I'm aware I'm in a technical forum and though my question is very technical to me this might not be the appropriate place to go. but I don't know where else to turn. I'm working with a technical partner and he created a hybrid app. It is a learning app that needs to convey complex information and therefore it is important to display info-graphics that the user needs to zoom-in to be able to read the containing information. My partner tells me that pinch and zoom is not possible for hybrid apps (which I find hard to believe since after extensive research I couln't find this explicit restriction anywhere) and there would be no solution to my problem. So now I'm trying now myself to find a solution.

Thank you for your patience

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just removing `maximum-scale=1` and setting `user-scalable=yes` on the viewport, you should be able to zoom.

You can find more about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

Answer (score 0):

Havent found pinch/zoom in Onsen doc.

But take a look at https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom

Jquery javascript for pinch and zoom any dom element :)