# What is the use of user-scalable in this scenario

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am trying to use the `viewport tag`. It is like this
`<meta name = "viewport" content = " width=device-width, height = device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale =1, minimum-scale =1, user-scalable=no">`
I am wondering since I disabled the zooming capabilities with the help of maximum-scale and minimum-scale. Can I **remove the user-scalable =no** altogether? Will there be any performant issues if I keep attributes in tags which are unnecessary?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the **user-scalable=no**.


"**minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1**" and "**user-scalable=no**" have same effect.


By the way, there will be no performance issues if you keep both attributes

**but** for cleaner codes just use one not both.

Comment: Can you please point to some links that can give some authority to your answer. If done, I'll be happy to accept your answer

Comment: @gates Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in

Comment: @gates By the way, I am currently developing a web app which is mobile responsive. So, I was able to try it.