# mobile browser initial zoom issue not fixed by meta tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile-browser

In a webpage I use the following markup to solve the initial zoom in mobile browsers:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

But the issue still exists.

Does anyone know how to solve the initial zoom issue in mobile browsers?

Comment: "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">" this doesn't fixed the isse

Comment: What issue are you talking about?

Comment: try this - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->

Comment: "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->" this also not working , still loading with a small amout of a zoom

Comment: Try with another browser profile. In mobile Firefox, the easiest way to do this is to install and run a beta or nightly version of Firefox besides the already installed stable one.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't the initial scale just set it so it defaults to normal? It won't stop zooming in.

There is no code to go by so I will take a shot in the dark and guess that there is an element on the page that it's focusing on? ie an input box. This will in fact cause a zoom to happen on page load. Does this happen on all pages?

If you could provide some code example and also a bit of a better explanation I think someone should be able to help you easier.

[What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

Thanks

Comment: Link to an explanation on different properties available

Comment: i get what u meant , but in this page there is no any input box or anything , this is just a DIV structure with some images, 
When researching i found that this initial zoom in mobile browser exits and it behaves like zoom in to the top left corner,

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to fix the issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```