# how to disable two finger pinch on Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, gesture, pinch

I'm developing this app http://test.app.upet.co and I need to disable the two finger pinch.

This is the page before the two finger pinch

[image: Before two finger pinch]

And this is the page after the two finger pinch

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would you want to disable it? If the user wants to zoom out why prevent it?

Comment: Hi there, I think using the <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"> tag will get what you want. Have a look at the related explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in

Comment: @nnnnnn—completely agree. Right up there with disabling zoom and landscape mode, totally user unfriendly.

Comment: Because the client asked for it sadly, @Kenrick I already have the meta tag on my page [Page](http://test.app.upet.co/signin) but it does not work

Comment: No. Zooming in makes parts of my webpage inaccessible. I was to disable it and as a web developer that decision must be left with me not apple. Stop selling kool-aid masquerading as an accessibilty feature.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` add this  to your head `<html><head>`

refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: I have already the meta on my page, [link](http://test.app.upet.co/) but it does not work

Comment: @DanielFJaramillo have you tested on other devices? Maybe this browser had some default setting changed.

Comment: @JohLin I have test it on two different devices, same result