# Smalltalk Seaside - How do I change the size of a button?

Tags: html, smalltalk, seaside

I am writing a Smalltalk Seaside app where the resulting HTML pages will be viewed on a laptop/an iPad and/or an iPhone. The size of a standard submit or cancel button is fine on the laptop but way to small on the tablet or the phone. How do I change the size? I have the required style sheets for each type of viewer.

I have little experience in style sheets in Seaside so I have had difficulty getting anywhere with this.

I guess that I need to set a class and a size but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which style sheet you are using, but assuming is one of the kind of [Bootstrap](https://github.com/astares/Seaside-Bootstrap4) or [Material Design Lite](https://github.com/DuneSt/MaterialDesignLite) try adding this to your root component on the instance side:

```
updateRoot: anHtmlRoot

    super updateRoot: anHtmlRoot.
    anHtmlRoot meta
        name: 'viewport';
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
```

This will add the correspoding `<meta>` tag to the `<head>` element in your page, producing the following HTML output:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will indicate the browser how to scale the contents.
For additional info, see this question: [What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

Comment: @LongHairedDavid did you find this answer useful? If so, can you mark it as the valid answer?