# Particular webpage appears zoomed in by 10% even though zoom level set to 100% on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

My Wordpress site appears zoomed in by exactly 10% and is only displayed correctly when I set it to 90% on Chrome.

I checked the Chrome settings and can see that pre-defined zoom level is set to 100%.

I know that website is zoomed in because I can compare it with the identical website which is being run on localhost using Chrome.

This problem is also prevalent when I use the Chrome's incognito mode.

Website, however, is displayed correctly when using Safari.

I already cleared the cache.

No errors are being displayed.

Any ideas what could be the reason? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include that meta in your `head` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Source : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)