# Why Position Fixed does not work on Mobile without minimum-scale

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, viewport

I saw many posts facing a problem that div adding `position:fixed` still moves on **mobile** browsers, and solved by setting viewport `minimum-scale=1.0`. (After some testing I think it's fixed by setting `minimum-scale` to match the `initial-scale`, or remove both `initial-scale` and `minimum-scale`). By definition `minimum-scale` only defines the minimum zoom, **why does this fixes the problem**?

Here are posts asking the same problem and solved by adding minimum-scale. None of them gives a reason why this works: (There is a comment mentioned that it could be components with width over 100vw causing the problem, **which is the case**, but it still didn't give a reason why adding `minimum-scale` fixes the problem.)

- [position: fixed doesn't work on chrome/firefox mobile mockup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926484/position-fixed-doesnt-work-on-chrome-firefox-mobile-mockup-and-mobile-but-w)
- [Position fixed on chrome mobile causing element to move on scroll up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680066/9107694)
- [position:fixed element just not staying fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302632/positionfixed-element-just-not-staying-fixed/)

This is my code for testing (On mobile, removing `minimum-scale=1.1` breaks `position:fixed`):

```css
.mylist {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
}

.placeholder {
    height: 150vh;
    width: 101vw;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.1, minimum-scale=1.1">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="placeholder">TEST</div>
    <div class="mylist">
        <ul>
            <li>t0</li>
            <li>t1</li>
            <li>t2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain according to my understanding.

The viewport meta tag came in html5 somewhere in between 2008 to 2014 and this meta tag was not there in html4. They introduced in HTML5 means there was a necessity for it because of the advent of the mobile devices. In those days, You can find horizontal scroll bar in many mobile devices while opening website because the width of the content of the desktop sites will be much higher than that of the mobile. (They wouldn't have given width in percentage as well)

In the case of desktop devices, We all know that the screen width is nothing but the number of pixels given as width part of the resolution. For instance, if the resolution is 1920 x 1080, It clearly states the screen size is 1920px.

But this is not the thing in case of mobile device. For example, Maybe the resolution of a mobile device will be 1080 x 2400 px. But when we write in mediascreen css, The same 1080px will be considered as 412 px by a mobile device. And this 1080/420 ratio is not fixed for all the devices. This ratio varies from brand to brand. There is something called resolution ratio which was specified by the mobile manufacturer. That is if the resolution ratio is 2.6, It means 1080 pixel of width will be considered as 412px (1080 /412 = 2.6). If the resolution ratio is 3, 1080 px of width will be considered as 360px(1080/3 = 360). By adapting this, a single css in px can be understood by all mobile devices.

Here the other position properties viz., absolute, relative and all are the position of the element with respect to **the content.** But position : fixed is with respect to viewport. For example, If you mention "position:absolute;top:0;right:100px;"  - with the olden system - in a smaller width monitor you have to scroll right if the content width is more than the monitor width, to see this. But if you mention, "position:fixed;right:100px" means, irrespective of the content size the element will be placed 100px from right end of the viewport.

So naturally the viewport dependent properties can work properly only after the advent of viewport metatag.

Comment: I understand `position:fixed` is with respect to viewport, but this doesn't explain why setting `minimum-scale` explicitly that shouldn't effect the `initial-zoom` will effect any outcome. I would guess it is something related to the [constraining procedure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#constraining-procedure) for the [actual-viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#actual-viewport)?